# How to update a textview from one fragment to an other fragment on same activity in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have single Activity and 2 fragments.Tab screen is divided into 2 parts.User Edit in editfield and press button(from FragmentA) then a textview should be updated that is on fragmentB on same Screen.[image]

```
YourNewFragment ldf = new YourNewFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("YourKey", "YourValue");
        ldf.setArguments(args);

        // Inflate the fragment
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, ldf)
                .commit();
```

here is Fragment B In onCreateView of the new Fragment:

```
String value = getArguments().getString("YourKey");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to create a callback on Fragment A which triggers a method on Fragment B.

Fragment A:

```
private FragmentCallback mCallback;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCallback.buttonPressed(textView.getText().toString());
        }
    });

}

public void setCallback(FragmentCallback callback) {
    mCallback = callback;
} 

public interface FragmentCallback {
    void buttonPressed(String value);
}
```

Fragment B:

```
@Override
public void buttonPressed(String value) {
    // do something here with value
}
```

Activity:

```
fragmentA.setCallback(fragmentB);
```

Just be sure Fragment B implements the FragmentCallback interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method in your YourActivity class

```
public void switchToFragmentB(String TextViewString)
{
    FragmentB fragment = new FragmentB();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("key", TextViewString);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
}
```

When button clicked from FragmentA, call this method like that,

```
((YourActivity) getActivity).switchToFragmentB("Good");
```

At last, In FragmentB's onCreateView() method get your data in this way,

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
int myString = bundle.getString("key");
```

Thats it...!

Comment: use callback  method...no fankari

Comment: This is the way in which I use to pass data...! Sure **no fankari**

Comment: mama subha interview hai merva na dana

Answer (score -1):

I did something similar before by doing

```
TopActivity context = (TopActivity) this.getActivity();
```

I do this in one fragment grabbing a reference to the activity the fragment is in and from here I can use the variables/functions in the activity.  So I used that to pass info in to the other fragment.

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing? context is same for both fragments beacause of having same activity

Comment: Correct context is the same, due to them being part of the same activity.  With the above code though if you replace TopActivity with the class name of the activity they are in they should be above to use functions/variables of their activity this allows one fragment to communicate to another.  Because from their encompassing activity  data can be sent to the other fragment.  Information to update the textview.

Answer (score -1):

when add or replace any fragmen... add tag to the parameters of the add..

```
getFragmentManagerbegin....add(R.id.....,mFragment,"fragmenRight").....commit.
```

and later from the second fragment use MyFragment right = (MyFragment)getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragmentRight");

right.setText(...... creat any method..